# How do I get the values from associative array in classic ASP

Tags: forms, asp-classic, associative-array

I'm using classic ASP to process a form.

I'm familiar with how PHP handles forms with something like:

```
function respondWithVars(){
  foreach($_POST as $stuff)
  echo($stuff);
}
```

But how do I iterate through and return values from my form with ASP?

I've tried

```
Sub respondWithVars
    for each item in request.form()
        Response.Write("<p>"&item&"</p>")
    next
End Sub
```

But it returns the keys, not values.

Comment: And here I was trying to figure out how to do what you were doing accidentally. I needed a list of the keys.  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try instead:

```
Sub respondWithVars
    for each item in request.form()
        Response.Write("<p>" & item & ": " & request.form(item) & "</p>")
    next
End Sub
```

This will iterate through the posted parameters and write out the parameter name and value.

Comment: Thanks! Calling the value from the array in parenthesis worked!